# Limiting voltage

Tags: dc

I'm working on a project that takes a user supplied voltage to measure values with an adc. I need to find a way to limit the max voltage input to the device to 5v max DC.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: That depends on the range of your input voltage, whether it is single polarity, alternating polarity and, possibly, how fast it changes (dV/dt). If you limit the max voltage you won't be able to measure beyond that point. Please edit your question to add some specifications.

Comment: [Protecting ADC inputs](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/protecting-adc-inputs.html)

Comment: This may help you: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/431119/overvoltage-protection-with-zener-how-do-you-get-a-sharp-knee-clamp-for-analog/431135#431135

Comment: This may also help you protect an A/D, but there are some nuances: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/437723/protection-against-high-negative-voltage-for-arduino/437756#437756

Comment: Any suitable series R(10k) and Schottky diode to Vss will do this

Answer (score -1):

You have to first limit the current - add a resistor.

The voltage can be limited by a zener
clamping diodes may be better, to also protect against negative voltages.

https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/esd-diodes-as-voltage-clamps.html

See figure 2

and any additional ESD proection

Comment: Answers that consist mainly of a link to external resources are discouraged. Tomorrow some company buys Analog Devices, changes all of their websites, and the information is lost. Please describe the important parts of the information at that site (don't just copy/paste!)

Answer (score -1):

You need a zener clamper diode that will limit the voltage to 5V and it won't let the voltage rise on input side. You can find one by writing "zener voltage regulator/voltage limiter" on google. You will find a zener diode with a parallely connected resistor.